# What does "jettisoned" next to my app name in a crash log signify?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, memory

My app crashes several times without any error or stack trace on my console. Then the only way left is to go and check Apple's crash reporter. I found "jettisoned" next to my app name, which in turn implies iOS killed my app, but how do I figure out why did it happened? Why is iOS killing my app? Initially, I thought it was a memory overflow issue, but then, using Instruments, I figured out that my app was taking hardly 4-5 MB of memory, so I discarded those issues. Apple's doc does not mention much about this. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[image: Crash Report]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means the process was terminated because iOS needed memory:

> Memory usage of each process is reported in terms of number of memory pages, which as of this writing are 4KB each. *You will see "(jettisoned)" next to the name of any process terminated by iOS to free up memory*. If you see it next to your application's name, that confirms the application was terminated for using too much memory.
>
> [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

I would take a look at that technical note for some additional help. The documentation also points out the Instruments does not measure graphics memory use, and that requires special handling.

Comment: ok I have added my crash report image now with this how do I figure out which process within my application has been terminated ... I just now that there is some memory issue but no other information apart of that .. I don't know about VM tracker ... I will try that out and get back to you

Comment: @KunalBalani ArchiveExplorer is using 141 *megabytes* of memory. The count means the number of allocated memory pages. 1 page = 4 KB (see documentation in my answer). So `36249 * 4 / 1024 ≈ 141`. ArchiveExplorer is using way too much memory.